# Unable to implement V6 in LWC component using JS

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar-6

The full calendar is not working with V6 in LWC Component.
It throws error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'changeView') when trying to call the ChangeView method from JS

The Fullcalendar was working fine with V5 on click of ChangeView.It should work with V6

Comment: Could you please add your code snippet for reference so that It can be helpful in understanding the issue ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.